# Chat with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, chat

I have two python scripts (provided by my instructor).

- `getchat.py` takes no params and it returns all messages in JSON a table of objects that contains date, time , user and the message .
- `sendchat.py` which takes a message and returns in JSON an object with two fields num that can be either 1,0 for : the message is empty or it was successfully added respectively .

What I want to do is when a user tries to send a message it use `sendchat.py` to post the msg in the database and use `getchat.py` afterwards to get all messages and show them.

```
<div id="chatmsg"></div>
<div id="cwrapper">
    <input class="msg" type="text" id="msg" name="msg">
    <button id="send">Send</button>
</div>
```

My jQuery script so far (I used some functions that were used documentation just to try)

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('./getchat.py', function(data){
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(d) {
            items.push("<li>" + d + "</li>");
        });

        $("<ul/>", {
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo("#chatmsg");
    });

    $.post("./sendchat.py", { msg: $("#msg").val() }, function(data, status) {
        // I don't know how to deal with this.
    });
});
```

All I get is a list `0,1,2,...` each time that I press send. The list appears for half a second and disappears. Where did I go wrong? How can I implement this properly? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Use ready to get the chats

```html
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $.getJSON('./getchat.py', function(data){
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(d) {
            items.push("<li>" + d + "</li>");
        });

        $("<ul/>", {
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo("#chatmsg");
    });
    });


// this is to post a message
$("button").click(function() {
    
    $.post("./sendchat.py", { msg: $("#msg").val() }, function(data, status) {
        // I don't know how to deal with this.
// Get the messages, better if only get the last
$.getJSON('./getchat.py', function(data){
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(d) {
            items.push("<li>" + d + "</li>");
        });

        $("<ul/>", {
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo("#chatmsg");
    });


    });
});
```

I don't try this code, but you can be an idea

Comment: Yes , this helps , but still the messages don't get POSTed on the server for some reason. And do have an Idea on how to show messages on my div #chatmsg from the JSON ?! I tried JSON.parse on the object but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Yes, you need use parse

Answer (score 0):

```html
$.getJSON('./getchat.py', function(data){



      //First show the data on your browser inspector NOT EMPTY
    console.log(data);
       
      //Later you need parse JSON
      var j = JSON.parse(data);

  //See in inspector
  console.log(j);

  //you can display your object and fields
// For example    j.message or j[0].message

// A for o foreach like you preffer, something like this

        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(d) {
            items.push("<li>" + d + "</li>");
        });

        $("<ul/>", {
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo("#chatmsg");
    });
```